# hide rows with zero value -- crystal reports

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2010

I have the following table in Crystal Reports 2010:

```
Name------------Number----Line----Price-----InvoiceNum 

CustomerX-------800---------2------$100----------1 
CustomerX-------800---------4------$0-------------1 
CustomerX-------800---------4------$0-------------1 
CustomerX-------800---------4------$900----------1 
CustomerX-------800---------3------$0-------------1 
CustomerX-------800---------3------$0-------------1 
CustomerX-------800---------3------$1900---------1 
CustomerX-------800---------2------$0-------------1 
CustomerX-------800---------2------$0-------------1
```

I want to suppress the rows that are duplicates and have $0 value, so I need something like this:

```
CustomerX-------800---------2------$100----------1 
CustomerX-------800---------4------$900----------1 
CustomerX-------800---------3------$1900---------1
```

At section expert if I use this formula for suppressing it will hide all rows that have Price as $0 value:

```
if {@Price}=0 then true else false
```

But I only want to hide the $0 value if there are duplicate Line numbers for same InvoiceNum.

I also tried this:

```
if ({@Price}=0 and {@Price}=previous({@Price})) then true else false
```

But it would not remove all of the zero-values, just a part.

Comment: what do you mean by duplicate Line numbers for same InvoiceNum?

Comment: you need to provide some variety of data.. your data has duolicate line numbers and all invoice numbers are same hard to understand your requirements

Comment: Ok, for some reason this report displays 0$ for a line of an invoice.

Comment: My invoices can have multiple lines, so in particular this invoice has 4 lines.
I don't want to have in my report lines with $0 value.
It's strange because for other customers, the data is displayed correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Go Report >Selection Formula>Record then Select your Fields As is

```
{Supplier.ClosingBalance} <>0
```

Comment: this is not working. just showing true or false. but the question is that hide the value if it is 0.